# Wait a result for a API inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm new to Node and I tried to understand promises, but it's kinda complicated.
I'm trying to call an API many times and then return my result. But my route sends a response first.

I want to return my response only after I finish the loop

```
data = {}
req.body.words.forEach(function (word) {

    newsapi.v2.everything({
        q: word,
        domains: req.body.domains.join(', '),
        sort_by: 'relevancy'
        })
        .then(response => {

            data[word]=response;
        })
    });

    return res.json(data);
```

It returns a empty array.

Comment: Would suggest you take a look at Node's event-loop to understand the asynchronous nature of Node better :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is synchronous it is initiating the async calls but never waits for them.
Either you can use `Promise.all` to get all the result parallely. Or can use `async-await` in parallel or serial manner.

```
data = {}
const promises = [];
req.body.words.forEach(function (word) {

    const promise = newsapi.v2.everything({
        q: word,
        domains: req.body.domains.join(', '),
        sort_by: 'relevancy'
    })
        .then(response => {

            data[word] = response;
        })
    promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
.then(()=>{
    res.send(data);
})
```

I have made a medium post for the exact same problem: https://medium.com/trappedpanda/loops-asynchronous-functions-and-returning-collective-results-in-node-js-b7566285fb74

Comment: Great post and a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is because requests are asynchronus, you need a work around in order to hold on to the result until all requests are completed, you can achieve that by a counter like so:

```
data = {}
let count = 0;
req.body.words.forEach(function (word) {
    count++;
    return newsapi.v2.everything({
        q: word,
        domains: req.body.domains.join(', '),
        sort_by: 'relevancy'
        })
        .then(response => {
            data[word]=response;
            //return only if all the entries are processed
            if (count === req.body.words.length) {
                return res.json(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped resolved your issue so that we may close this thread on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
let promisesToAwait = [];
let words = req.body.words;
for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
   promisesToAwait.push(await this.loopThruAllWords(words[j], req.body.domains.join(', ')));
}
let allResponses = await Promise.all(promisesToAwait1);

async loopThruAllWords(word, domains){
let response = await newsapi.v2.everything({
    q: word,
    domains: domains,
    sort_by: 'relevancy'
    });
return Promise.resolve(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "for-async" npm:

```
   var forAsync = require("for-async");

    data = {}
     forAsync(req.body.words, function (word, i) {
          return new Promise(function (next) {

            newsapi.v2.everything({
              q: word,
              domains: req.body.domains.join(', '),
              sort_by: 'relevancy'
              })
              .then(response => {
                data[word]=response;
                next(); //go to the next iteration
            });

          });
      }).then(() => {
         console.log("Loop finished");
         return res.json(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

For-each loop can't wait for async-await. so, instead of for-each, you need to use for loop and do your code inside of for loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 await apicall();
}
```